# How to speed asyncio up?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

I know this has been asked many times, but none of the solutions worked for my code (or I am too stupid to implent them correctly), but I have a problem with an asynchronous request in Python. I am trying to process around 40 000 pdfs and it is quite slow. My code is as follows:

```
async def post_file(data, token, mime_type, filename, summarize=False):
    global logs
    xml_post = prepare_file_for_post(data, token, mime_type, filename)
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=200),headers=headers) as session:
        start_time = datetime.now()
        async with session.post(url, data=xml_post) as response:
            end_time = datetime.now()
            logging.info("Done processing|" + filename + "|in|" + str((end_time - start_time).total_seconds()))
            resp = await response.content.read()
            if summarize:
                return read_recognized_text_from_response(resp)
            else:
                return read_entire_response(resp)


def write_summarized_result_to_file(barcode_1, barcode_2, recognized_text, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        if barcode_1 != None:
            f.write("Barcode 1: " + str(barcode_1.text) + "\n")
        else:
            f.write("Barcode 1: None\n")
        if barcode_2 != None:
            f.write("Barcode 2: " + str(barcode_2.text) + "\n")
        else:
            f.write("Barcode 2: None\n")
        f.write("------------------------------------" + "\n\n")
        for item in recognized_text:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
            
            
def write_entire_result_to_file(result, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(result)

            
async def analyze_file(input_folder, filename, token, semaphore):
    await semaphore.acquire()
    data, mime_type = read_file(input_folder + '/' + filename)
    if entire_output:
        result = await post_file(data, token, mime_type, filename)
        write_entire_result_to_file(result, output_folder + today + '_' + str(filename) + '.xml')
    else:
        barcode_1, barcode_2, recognized_text = await post_file(data, token, mime_type, filename, True)
        write_summarized_result_to_file(barcode_1, barcode_2, recognized_text, output_folder + today + '_' + str(filename) + '.txt')
    semaphore.release()
    
    
async def main(input_folder, token):
    ocr_task = []
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(value=4)
    for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
         if filename.endswith('pdf') or filename.endswith('jpg') or filename.endswith('png') or filename.endswith('jpeg') or filename.endswith('tif') or filename.endswith('tiff'):
            ocr_task = asyncio.create_task(analyze_file(input_folder, filename, token, semaphore))
    try:
        await asyncio.wait([ocr_task])
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("An error occured|" + e)
```

And the way I start the process:

```
token = authorize()
start_time_total = datetime.now()
await main(input_folder, token)
end_time_total = datetime.now()
logging.info("Done processing|all Files|in|" + str((end_time_total - start_time_total).total_seconds()))
```

If somebody could point out to my mistake, that would be awesome, because I kind of tried everything I found.

Comment: Have you considered refactoring for multithreading? You are logging the start/end times for the POST. Is that slow?

Comment: Not sure asyncio best suits your use case.
Asyncio will speed up I/O bound code by making non blocking calls and delegating I/O to an event loop.
Here it looks like your problem (supposition from what I read) is quite CPU-bound. If analyzing pfds (with ocr inside ?) requires processing and processing is the bottleneck, I"d recommend to think about a multiprocessing solution.
Anyway if you put on the asyncio event loop long-duration tasks, the loop will be busy and you won't benefit any more from it.

Comment: @0x0fba that sounds like a nice idea, I will try it !